# How do I use dask to efficiently compute custom statistics?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

**Problem**

I have a custom class `CachedStatistics` that holds, among other things, a dask dataframe. It also has customly defined methods that can depend on dask methods or other customly defined methods.

This class is intended to be an extension of a dask.dataframe, with new operations that are not present in dask originally.

A simplified implementation is the following:

```
class CachedStatistics:
    def __init__(self, parquet)
        self.df = dd.read_parquet(parquet)
        self.cached = ..

    # method to implement cache
    def _call_method(self, name):
        if self.cached[name] is None:
            self.cached[name] = self.getattr(name).__call__()

        return self.cached[name]

    def nrows(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def count(self):
        return self.df.count()

    def missing_pct(self):
        return self._call_method("nrows") / self._call_method("count")

    def test_missing(self):
        if self._call_method("missing_pct") < 0.5:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def col_mean(self, col)
        return self.df[col].mean()

    def summary(self):
        df_dict = { 
            'missing_pct': self._call_method("missing_pct") , 
            'mean' : self._call_method("mean")
        }

        return pd.Series(df_dict)
```

## My major requirements are:

### Cache all computations

I want to, for example, be able call call `dask.compute` on `missing_pct()` and have this not only save the result for `missing_pct()` but also for every dependency (`nrows()` and `count()`).

I tried to find a way to do this in case I implemented custom collections, but couldn't figure out how.

### Optimize computations

I want to be able to compute several stats with a single dask.compute(), to avoid overhead and maximize performance.

### Implementation

I have tried to make every method delayed, but the nested delayed objects don't get computed when I call compute on the outer method, because of the way dask unpacks delayed objects.
Example:
[image: nested delayed objects]

From what I read from the docs, having all my methods output a HighLevelGraph seems the way to go, but I'm unsure as to how to translate my currently defined methods to a dictionary of dependencies, since I would very much prefer to be able to define methods as they are now.

Thanks for any help or guiding suggestions.

Comment: I think this is possible through Dask Distributed’s Cache object: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/caching.html

Comment: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/caching.html